# XSLT transform with templates: remove empty xmlns=""

Tags: xslt, xml-namespaces

How do I remove the empty `xmlns=""` in my transformation?

Below is the example of what shows up in the resulting XML. Notice the empty `xmlns`.

I'm working with VisualStudio 2019 16.8.4.

This is the source XML that I need to transform.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wPOREQ payloadID='113084912-000001' timestamp='2020-12-16T14:05:36-06:00' version='3.1'>
  <Header mode='Production'>
    <From>
      <Credential domain='DUNS'>
        <Identity>060480999</Identity>
      </Credential>
    </From>
    <To>
      <Credential domain='DUNS'>
        <Identity>060480999</Identity>
      </Credential>
    </To>
    <Sender>
      <Credential domain='DUNS'>
        <Identity>196488888</Identity>
        <SharedSecret>111</SharedSecret>
      </Credential>
    </Sender>
  </Header>
  <Order deploymentMode='production' rush='N'>
    <PONumber>59test</PONumber>
    <ReferenceNumber>59240249</ReferenceNumber>
    <WCSSCustomerId>0810999</WCSSCustomerId>
    <OrderExtrinsic>
      <Extrinsic name='PONUM'>MM000327999</Extrinsic>
    </OrderExtrinsic>
    <ShipTo>
      <WCSSShipTo>0001</WCSSShipTo>
      <LocationCode/>
      <Name1>SHIP TO THIS</Name1>
      <Name2/>
      <Address1>99 MEDICAL CENTER DRIVE</Address1>
      <Address2>HSC BMRC</Address2>
      <Address3>BK TEST</Address3>
      <City>ANYTOWN</City>
      <State>WV</State>
      <ZipCode>265053409</ZipCode>
      <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
      <Phone>
        <AreaCode/>
        <PhNumber/>
        <Ext/>
      </Phone>
      <Fax>
        <AreaCode/>
        <PhNumber/>
        <Ext/>
      </Fax>
      <Attention>RM:8707</Attention>
      <Email/>
    </ShipTo>
    <OrderDate>2020-12-16T14:05:36-06:00</OrderDate>
    <DeliverByDate>2021-01-31</DeliverByDate>
    <RequestedShipDate/>
    <RequestedCarrier>UPSS</RequestedCarrier>
    <ShippingMessage>CUST CARRIER ACCT: 021FW0</ShippingMessage>
    <LineItems>
      <LineItem>
        <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
        <SKU>10037475</SKU>
        <SKUDescription>WVU LETTERHEAD</SKUDescription>
        <Quantity>1000</Quantity>
        <OrderUOM>SH</OrderUOM>
        <UnitPrice currency='USD'>125.50</UnitPrice>
        <NameFromBC/>
        <Phone1FromBC/>
        <EmailFromBC>katharine.belcher</EmailFromBC>
        <DeliverByDate/>
        <RequestedShipDate>2021-01-31</RequestedShipDate>
        <LineMessage>PRINT 1 COPY(S) OF ALL PDF FIL</LineMessage>
        <LineMessage>ES STARTING WITH: 59240249 WVU</LineMessage>
        <SupplierAuxPartId/>
        <LineItemExtrinsic>
          <Extrinsic name='PriceUOM'>M</Extrinsic>
        </LineItemExtrinsic>
      </LineItem>
    </LineItems>
  </Order>
</wPOREQ>
```

Here is what I produced for the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">
      <Header>
        <MessageId>
          <!--<xsl:value-of select="Header/MessageId"/>-->
        </MessageId>
        <Action>http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/services/SalesOrderService/create</Action>
      </Header>
      <Body>
        <MessageParts xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">
          <SalesOrder xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesOrder">
            <SalesTable class="entity">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="wPOREQ/Order"/>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="wPOREQ/Order/ShipTo"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="wPOREQ/Order/LineItems/LineItem"/>
            </SalesTable>
          </SalesOrder>
        </MessageParts>
      </Body>
    </Envelope>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="wPOREQ/Order">
      <CustAccount>
        <xsl:value-of select="WCSSCustomerId"/>
      </CustAccount>
      <CustomerRef>
        <xsl:value-of select="ReferenceNumber"/>
      </CustomerRef>
      <InventLocationId>
        <xsl:value-of select="WCSSCustomerId"/>
      </InventLocationId>
      <InventSiteId>
        <xsl:value-of select="WCSSCustomerId"/>
      </InventSiteId>
      <InvoiceAccount>
        <xsl:value-of select="WCSSCustomerId"/>
      </InvoiceAccount>
      <ProductType>
        <xsl:value-of select="WCSSCustomerId"/>
      </ProductType>
      <PurchOrderFormNum>
        <xsl:value-of select="PONumber"/>
      </PurchOrderFormNum>
      <ReceiptDateRequested>
        <xsl:value-of select="DeliverByDate"/>
      </ReceiptDateRequested>
      <SalesGroup>
        <xsl:value-of select="WCSSCustomerId"/>
      </SalesGroup>
      <SalesPoolId>
        <xsl:value-of select="10" />
      </SalesPoolId>
      <ShipCarrierDeliveryContact>
        <xsl:value-of select="ShipTo/Attention"/>
      </ShipCarrierDeliveryContact>
    </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="ShipTo">
    <TableDlvAddr class="entity">
      <City>
        <xsl:value-of select="City"/>
      </City>
      <CountryRegionId>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="CountryCode = 'US'">USA</xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="USA" />
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </CountryRegionId>
      <LocationName>
        <xsl:value-of select="Name1"/>
      </LocationName>
      <State>
        <xsl:value-of select="State"/>
      </State>
      <Street>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(Address1,'&#xd;', Address2,'&#xd;', Address3)"/>
      </Street>
      <ZipCode>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(ZipCode,1,5)"/>
      </ZipCode>
    </TableDlvAddr>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="LineItem">
    <SalesLine class="entity">
      <CustomerRef>
                <xsl:value-of select="../../ReferenceNumber"/>
            </CustomerRef>
      <ItemId>
        <xsl:value-of select="SKU"/>
      </ItemId>
      <LineNum>
        <xsl:value-of select="LineNumber"/>
      </LineNum>
      <PurchorderFormNum>
        <xsl:value-of select="../../PONumber"/>
      </PurchorderFormNum>
      <SalesPrice>
        <xsl:value-of select="UnitPrice"/>
      </SalesPrice>
      <SalesQty>
        <xsl:value-of select="Quantity"/>
      </SalesQty>
      <SalesUnit>
        <xsl:value-of select="OrderUOM"/>
      </SalesUnit>      
    </SalesLine>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, the output produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">
  <Header>
    <MessageId />
    <Action>http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/services/SalesOrderService/create</Action>
  </Header>
  <Body>
    <MessageParts>
      <SalesOrder xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesOrder">
        <SalesTable class="entity">
          <CustAccount xmlns="">0810147</CustAccount>
          <CustomerRef xmlns="">BK012521-01</CustomerRef>
          <InventLocationId xmlns="">0810147</InventLocationId>
          <InventSiteId xmlns="">0810147</InventSiteId>
          <InvoiceAccount xmlns="">0810147</InvoiceAccount>
          <ProductType xmlns="">0810147</ProductType>
          <PurchOrderFormNum xmlns="">595280620001b3</PurchOrderFormNum>
          <ReceiptDateRequested xmlns="">2021-01-31</ReceiptDateRequested>
          <SalesGroup xmlns="">0810147</SalesGroup>
          <SalesPoolId xmlns="">10</SalesPoolId>
          <ShipCarrierDeliveryContact xmlns="">RM:8707,SALLY WEAVER</ShipCarrierDeliveryContact>
          <TableDlvAddr class="entity" xmlns="">
            <City>MORGANTOWN</City>
            <CountryRegionId>USA</CountryRegionId>
            <LocationName>WEST VIRGINIA UNIVERSITY</LocationName>
            <State>WV</State>
            <Street>
              64 MEDICAL CENTER DRIVE
              HSC BMRC
              BK TEST
            </Street>
            <ZipCode>26505</ZipCode>
          </TableDlvAddr>
          <SalesLine class="entity" xmlns="">
            <CustomerRef>BK012521-01</CustomerRef>
            <ItemId>10037475</ItemId>
            <LineNum>1</LineNum>
            <PurchorderFormNum>595280620001b3</PurchorderFormNum>
            <SalesPrice>125.50</SalesPrice>
            <SalesQty>1000</SalesQty>
            <SalesUnit>SH</SalesUnit>
          </SalesLine>
        </SalesTable>
      </SalesOrder>
    </MessageParts>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Desired output is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">
  <Header>
    <MessageId />
    <Action>http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/services/SalesOrderService/create</Action>
  </Header>
  <Body>
    <MessageParts>
      <SalesOrder xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesOrder">
        <SalesTable class="entity">
          <CustAccount>0810147</CustAccount>
          <CustomerRef>59240249</CustomerRef>
          <InventLocationId>0810147</InventLocationId>
          <InventSiteId>0810147</InventSiteId>
          <InvoiceAccount>0810147</InvoiceAccount>
          <ProductType>0810147</ProductType>
          <PurchOrderFormNum>595280620001</PurchOrderFormNum>
          <ReceiptDateRequested>2021-01-31</ReceiptDateRequested>
          <SalesGroup>0810147</SalesGroup>
          <SalesPoolId>10</SalesPoolId>
          <ShipCarrierDeliveryContact>RM:8707</ShipCarrierDeliveryContact>
          <TableDlvAddr class="entity">
            <City>MORGANTOWN</City>
            <CountryRegionId>USA    </CountryRegionId>
            <LocationName>WEST VIRGINIA UNIVERSITY</LocationName>
            <State>WV</State>
            <Street>64 MEDICAL CENTER DRIVE
HSC BMRC
BK TEST</Street>
            <ZipCode>26505</ZipCode>
          </TableDlvAddr>
          <SalesLine class="entity">
            <CustomerRef>59240249</CustomerRef>
            <ItemId>10037475</ItemId>
            <LineNum>1</LineNum>
            <PurchOrderFormNum>595280620001</PurchOrderFormNum>
            <SalesPrice>125.50</SalesPrice>
            <SalesQty>1000</SalesQty>
            <SalesUnit>SH</SalesUnit>
          </SalesLine>
        </SalesTable>
      </SalesOrder>
    </MessageParts>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Comment: Do you want those elements that currently are in the "no namespace" to be bound a namespace, or just don't want to see the empty namespace declaration repeated? You aren't using namespace prefixes for any of the other elements that are bound to a namespace, so it has to disambiguate and re-declare what namespace (or `""` none) at the moment. Maybe you could post an example of the desired output as well in your question?

Comment: I do NOT want those elements to be bound to a namespace and would like to entirely remove the empty xmlns="".

Comment: what about the elements that are bound to a namespace? Is there a reason not to use namespace-prefixes for them?

Comment: I added my desired output to the question. It was created using an alternate xslt where I use <xsl:for-each> on <SalesLine>.  I'm trying to learn templates.

Comment: ah, so you want those elements bound to the Sales Order namespace

Comment: It is much easier to tell, when you use namespace prefixes. If there is no prefix, and you mix namespaces, then they need to get redefined with the explicit `xmlns` when it changes and it makes it a little harder to see which namespace they are bound to which are "inherited" from their ancestor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare those namespaces with namespace-prefixes in your stylesheet, and use those namespace-prefixes on the elements that you do want bound to a namespace.

Then the elements which are not bound to a namespace will be serialized without a prefix and won't have to re-declare that the namespace is empty:

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message"
    xmlns:so="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesOrder">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <m:Envelope>
            <m:Header>
                <m:MessageId>
                    <!--<xsl:value-of select="Header/MessageId"/>-->
                </m:MessageId>
                <m:Action>http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/services/SalesOrderService/create</m:Action>
            </m:Header>
            <m:Body>
                <m:MessageParts>
                    <so:SalesOrder>
                        <so:SalesTable class="entity">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="wPOREQ/Order"/>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="wPOREQ/Order/ShipTo"/>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="wPOREQ/Order/LineItems/LineItem"/>
                        </so:SalesTable>
                    </so:SalesOrder>
                </m:MessageParts>
            </m:Body>
        </m:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="wPOREQ/Order">
        <CustAccount>
            <xsl:value-of select="WCSSCustomerId"/>
        </CustAccount>
        <CustomerRef>
            <xsl:value-of select="ReferenceNumber"/>
        </CustomerRef>
        <InventLocationId>
            <xsl:value-of select="WCSSCustomerId"/>
        </InventLocationId>
        <InventSiteId>
            <xsl:value-of select="WCSSCustomerId"/>
        </InventSiteId>
        <InvoiceAccount>
            <xsl:value-of select="WCSSCustomerId"/>
        </InvoiceAccount>
        <ProductType>
            <xsl:value-of select="WCSSCustomerId"/>
        </ProductType>
        <PurchOrderFormNum>
            <xsl:value-of select="PONumber"/>
        </PurchOrderFormNum>
        <ReceiptDateRequested>
            <xsl:value-of select="DeliverByDate"/>
        </ReceiptDateRequested>
        <SalesGroup>
            <xsl:value-of select="WCSSCustomerId"/>
        </SalesGroup>
        <SalesPoolId>
            <xsl:value-of select="10" />
        </SalesPoolId>
        <ShipCarrierDeliveryContact>
            <xsl:value-of select="ShipTo/Attention"/>
        </ShipCarrierDeliveryContact>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ShipTo">
        <TableDlvAddr class="entity">
            <City>
                <xsl:value-of select="City"/>
            </City>
            <CountryRegionId>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="CountryCode = 'US'">USA</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="USA" />
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </CountryRegionId>
            <LocationName>
                <xsl:value-of select="Name1"/>
            </LocationName>
            <State>
                <xsl:value-of select="State"/>
            </State>
            <Street>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(Address1,'&#xd;', Address2,'&#xd;', Address3)"/>
            </Street>
            <ZipCode>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(ZipCode,1,5)"/>
            </ZipCode>
        </TableDlvAddr>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="LineItem">
        <SalesLine class="entity">
            <CustomerRef>
                <xsl:value-of select="../../ReferenceNumber"/>
            </CustomerRef>
            <ItemId>
                <xsl:value-of select="SKU"/>
            </ItemId>
            <LineNum>
                <xsl:value-of select="LineNumber"/>
            </LineNum>
            <PurchorderFormNum>
                <xsl:value-of select="../../PONumber"/>
            </PurchorderFormNum>
            <SalesPrice>
                <xsl:value-of select="UnitPrice"/>
            </SalesPrice>
            <SalesQty>
                <xsl:value-of select="Quantity"/>
            </SalesQty>
            <SalesUnit>
                <xsl:value-of select="OrderUOM"/>
            </SalesUnit>      
        </SalesLine>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<m:Envelope xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message"
            xmlns:so="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesOrder">
   <m:Header>
      <m:MessageId/>
      <m:Action>http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/services/SalesOrderService/create</m:Action>
   </m:Header>
   <m:Body>
      <m:MessageParts>
         <so:SalesOrder>
            <so:SalesTable class="entity">
               <CustAccount>0810999</CustAccount>
               <CustomerRef>59240249</CustomerRef>
               <InventLocationId>0810999</InventLocationId>
               <InventSiteId>0810999</InventSiteId>
               <InvoiceAccount>0810999</InvoiceAccount>
               <ProductType>0810999</ProductType>
               <PurchOrderFormNum>59test</PurchOrderFormNum>
               <ReceiptDateRequested>2021-01-31</ReceiptDateRequested>
               <SalesGroup>0810999</SalesGroup>
               <SalesPoolId>10</SalesPoolId>
               <ShipCarrierDeliveryContact>RM:8707</ShipCarrierDeliveryContact>
               <TableDlvAddr class="entity">
                  <City>ANYTOWN</City>
                  <CountryRegionId>USA</CountryRegionId>
                  <LocationName>SHIP TO THIS</LocationName>
                  <State>WV</State>
                  <Street>99 MEDICAL CENTER DRIVE&#xD;HSC BMRC&#xD;BK TEST</Street>
                  <ZipCode>26505</ZipCode>
               </TableDlvAddr>
               <SalesLine class="entity">
                  <CustomerRef>59240249</CustomerRef>
                  <ItemId>10037475</ItemId>
                  <LineNum>1</LineNum>
                  <PurchorderFormNum>59test</PurchorderFormNum>
                  <SalesPrice>125.50</SalesPrice>
                  <SalesQty>1000</SalesQty>
                  <SalesUnit>SH</SalesUnit>
               </SalesLine>
            </so:SalesTable>
         </so:SalesOrder>
      </m:MessageParts>
   </m:Body>
</m:Envelope>
```

If you wanted those `SalesOrder` descendant elements which were being serialized in the "no namespace" to be bound to the sales order namespace, but still not have namespace prefixes, then declare the default namespace (no namespace-prefix) to be the sales order namespace and retain the explicit declaration of namespaces for the `Envelope` and `SalesOrder` elements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesOrder">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">
            <Header>
                <MessageId>
                    <!--<xsl:value-of select="Header/MessageId"/>-->
                </MessageId>
                <Action>http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/services/SalesOrderService/create</Action>
            </Header>
            <Body>
                <MessageParts>
                    <SalesOrder xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesOrder">
                        <SalesTable class="entity">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="wPOREQ/Order"/>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="wPOREQ/Order/ShipTo"/>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="wPOREQ/Order/LineItems/LineItem"/>
                        </SalesTable>
                    </SalesOrder>
                </MessageParts>
            </Body>
        </Envelope>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="wPOREQ/Order">
        <CustAccount>
            <xsl:value-of select="WCSSCustomerId"/>
        </CustAccount>
        <CustomerRef>
            <xsl:value-of select="ReferenceNumber"/>
        </CustomerRef>
        <InventLocationId>
            <xsl:value-of select="WCSSCustomerId"/>
        </InventLocationId>
        <InventSiteId>
            <xsl:value-of select="WCSSCustomerId"/>
        </InventSiteId>
        <InvoiceAccount>
            <xsl:value-of select="WCSSCustomerId"/>
        </InvoiceAccount>
        <ProductType>
            <xsl:value-of select="WCSSCustomerId"/>
        </ProductType>
        <PurchOrderFormNum>
            <xsl:value-of select="PONumber"/>
        </PurchOrderFormNum>
        <ReceiptDateRequested>
            <xsl:value-of select="DeliverByDate"/>
        </ReceiptDateRequested>
        <SalesGroup>
            <xsl:value-of select="WCSSCustomerId"/>
        </SalesGroup>
        <SalesPoolId>
            <xsl:value-of select="10" />
        </SalesPoolId>
        <ShipCarrierDeliveryContact>
            <xsl:value-of select="ShipTo/Attention"/>
        </ShipCarrierDeliveryContact>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ShipTo">
        <TableDlvAddr class="entity">
            <City>
                <xsl:value-of select="City"/>
            </City>
            <CountryRegionId>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="CountryCode = 'US'">USA</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="USA" />
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </CountryRegionId>
            <LocationName>
                <xsl:value-of select="Name1"/>
            </LocationName>
            <State>
                <xsl:value-of select="State"/>
            </State>
            <Street>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(Address1,'&#xd;', Address2,'&#xd;', Address3)"/>
            </Street>
            <ZipCode>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(ZipCode,1,5)"/>
            </ZipCode>
        </TableDlvAddr>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="LineItem">
        <SalesLine class="entity">
            <CustomerRef>
                <xsl:value-of select="../../ReferenceNumber"/>
            </CustomerRef>
            <ItemId>
                <xsl:value-of select="SKU"/>
            </ItemId>
            <LineNum>
                <xsl:value-of select="LineNumber"/>
            </LineNum>
            <PurchorderFormNum>
                <xsl:value-of select="../../PONumber"/>
            </PurchorderFormNum>
            <SalesPrice>
                <xsl:value-of select="UnitPrice"/>
            </SalesPrice>
            <SalesQty>
                <xsl:value-of select="Quantity"/>
            </SalesQty>
            <SalesUnit>
                <xsl:value-of select="OrderUOM"/>
            </SalesUnit>      
        </SalesLine>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which produces this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">
   <Header>
      <MessageId/>
      <Action>http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/services/SalesOrderService/create</Action>
   </Header>
   <Body>
      <MessageParts>
         <SalesOrder xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesOrder">
            <SalesTable class="entity">
               <CustAccount>0810999</CustAccount>
               <CustomerRef>59240249</CustomerRef>
               <InventLocationId>0810999</InventLocationId>
               <InventSiteId>0810999</InventSiteId>
               <InvoiceAccount>0810999</InvoiceAccount>
               <ProductType>0810999</ProductType>
               <PurchOrderFormNum>59test</PurchOrderFormNum>
               <ReceiptDateRequested>2021-01-31</ReceiptDateRequested>
               <SalesGroup>0810999</SalesGroup>
               <SalesPoolId>10</SalesPoolId>
               <ShipCarrierDeliveryContact>RM:8707</ShipCarrierDeliveryContact>
               <TableDlvAddr class="entity">
                  <City>ANYTOWN</City>
                  <CountryRegionId>USA</CountryRegionId>
                  <LocationName>SHIP TO THIS</LocationName>
                  <State>WV</State>
                  <Street>99 MEDICAL CENTER DRIVE&#xD;HSC BMRC&#xD;BK TEST</Street>
                  <ZipCode>26505</ZipCode>
               </TableDlvAddr>
               <SalesLine class="entity">
                  <CustomerRef>59240249</CustomerRef>
                  <ItemId>10037475</ItemId>
                  <LineNum>1</LineNum>
                  <PurchorderFormNum>59test</PurchorderFormNum>
                  <SalesPrice>125.50</SalesPrice>
                  <SalesQty>1000</SalesQty>
                  <SalesUnit>SH</SalesUnit>
               </SalesLine>
            </SalesTable>
         </SalesOrder>
      </MessageParts>
   </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Comment: Yes, the second version is what I'm after. Thank you very much for your help and helping me understand this a bit more.